# Way to remove reference from an array of references using a field of the referenced object in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I currently have 2 schemas

```
var GroupSchema = new Schema(
  {
    requests: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Request'}],
    questions: [{type: String}]
  }
);
```

and

```
var RequestSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    responses: [{type: String}],
    approval: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  }
);
```

Given the id of a User, is there a way for me to remove the references of requests with that user id from the requests array in Group?

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
const g = await Group
          .populate("request")
          .update{{$pull: {requests: {user: req.body.userid}}})
          .exec();
```